# Read access violation en un return

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente la funcion negocioValido llama existeNegocio, que chequea un archivo y devuelve si este negocio existe e el archivo o no, y devuelve el negocio encontrado por referencia (despues se hacen otras cosas con este).

En el return tira la excepcion de la imagen. No entiendo que parte de la funcion podria estar generando este problema ya que es una funcion sencilla. Usando el debugger el error se da en el return, no tengo idea que es la biblioteca donde se da la excepcion y no tuve suerte buscando las causas!

```
negocio negocioValido(unsigned short rubro) 
{
        string nombreNeg;
        negocio negIngresado;

        cout << "Ingrese nombre del comerio, rubro "<< rubros[rubro] << "." << endl;
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        getline(cin, nombreNeg);

        //aca esta el problema
        while (!existeNegocio(nombreNeg, rubro, negIngresado))
        {
            cout << nombreNeg << " no se encuentra entre los negocios inscriptos." << endl;
            cout << "Ingrese nombre del comerio:" << endl;
            cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            getline(cin, nombreNeg);
        }

        return negIngresado;
    }

bool existeNegocio(string nombreNeg, unsigned short rubro, negocio &negBuscado)
{
    bool encontrado = false;
    negocio negocioAux;

    //buscamos en el archivo del rubro correspondiente
    string fName = rubros[rubro] + ".dat";
    FILE* f_rubro = fopen(&fName[0], "r");

    //seguimos leyendo cada negocio mientras no lleguemos al eof y no se haya encontrado el buscado
    while (!encontrado && fread(&negocioAux, sizeof(negocio), 1, f_rubro) == 1)
    {
        if (negocioAux.nombre == nombreNeg)
        {
            encontrado = true;
            (negBuscado) = negocioAux;
        }
    }

    fclose(f_rubro);
    return encontrado;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido de `_Pnext`? a la hora de depurar?

Comment: la direccion de memoria que no se puede acceder (que aparece en la imagen). la verdad que no se que es, no conozco la biblioteca donde se da

Comment: Me refiero, has hecho debug? Porque solo parece que arroja la excepcion. Si usas VS como IDE, prueba a poner un breakpoint antes de la linea y ejecutar paso a paso cada instrucción para comprobar que el valor no es nulo.

Comment: lo habia hecho pero no con _Pnext, que no es nulo. En mis funciones todas las variables tienen los valores que deberian tomar.

Comment: no se si sirve de algo, pero haciendo el build en release en lugar de debug hace que no suceda. cambia la excepcion por " An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal." y todavia estoy viendo de que se trata

Comment: Realmente no tengo informacion suficiente, mi única sugerencia es que veas los datos internos de la excepcion para saber donde se origina el problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás en C++ y, sin embargo, usas los mecanismos de acceso a archivos propios de C ... y eso tiene sus implicaciones.

Veo que haces uso de `std::string`, así que imagino que la clase `negocio` tendrá un código similar al siguiente:

```
struct negocio
{
  std::string nombre;
};
```

Este punto es importante, ya que `std::string` hace uso de memoria dinámica, es decir, `std::string` es una clase que, básicamente, contiene un puntero a una dirección de memoria.

Si usas mecanismos propios de C, que implican accesos directos a memoria, al leer el archivo estarás modificando ese puntero, haciendo que apunte a una dirección de memoria no válida. El resultado es que al intentar leer su contenido el programa, presumiblemente, explotará ya que el Sistema Operativo detecta que tu programa intenta acceder a una dirección de memoria que no le pertenece.

Lo que tienes que hacer es programar las lecturas y escrituras usando los mecanismos propios de C++. Esto es, usando `std::ifstream` para la lectura y `std::ofstream` para la escritura:

```
std::ifstream file(fname, std::ifstream::in);
negocio.name << file;
```

De esta forma, evitarás que el estado de las clases (en especial los punteros) se queden en un estado inconsistente.

Comment: efectivamente era esto. por probar hace un rato cambie un string a char*, dejo de tirar la excepción y asumí que era algo del estilo pero sin estar seguro el por qué. gracias por la explicación